# Whats wrong with this expression? Is it evaluated from left to right meaning that the mistake is that a String is added to a double first?

Tags: java, string, boolean

If d1 and d2 are doubles with valid values, what is wrong with the following expression?

```
"answer = " + d1 < d2
```

Comment: Whats the programming language? Have you tried: `"answer  = " + (d1 < d2)`

Comment: its java real sorry

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: In other words: please describe *expected* and *actual* behavior; instead of going: "stuff not working".

Comment: yeah I have but i was wondering why would it not work? like just statement itself

Comment: I suggest you look at the order of evaluation of operands in java:
https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

Comment: The [Java operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) page shows that "additive" (+) operator are evaluated before "relational" (<) operators. So you will have a `String + double < double` -> `String < double` not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The [Java operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) page shows that "additive" (+) operator are evaluated before "relational" (<) operators.

So the statement `String + double < double` will be seen like :

```
String + double < double   ==   (String + double) < double --> String < double
```

The result will be `String < double`, that operation is not supported in java. So it will not compile.

Check the [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) array to find the exact order.

> The closer to the top of the table an operator appears, the higher its precedence
>
> Operators with higher precedence are evaluated before operators with relatively lower precedence
>
> When operators of equal precedence appear in the same expression, a rule must govern which is evaluated first :
>
> - All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from left to right;
> - assignment operators are evaluated right to left.